# Change size of selected math alphabets

Tags: fontsize, math-fonts

I'm caught in the crossfire between an author and a publisher with an unpleasant `sty` file `:-)` The publisher redefines `\normalsize` to be 9.5pt and changes the math sizes correspondingly. Using `lmodern` this is not a problem for most symbols, but there are issues with `bbm` and `mathrsfs`. The code

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{mathrsfs,bbm}

\makeatletter
% taken from the sty file I must use
\renewcommand\normalsize{%
   \@setfontsize\normalsize{9.5}{13}%
   \abovedisplayskip9.5\p@\@plus2\p@\@minus5\p@
   \abovedisplayshortskip\z@\@plus3\p@
   \belowdisplayshortskip6\p@\@plus3\p@\@minus3\p@
   \belowdisplayskip\abovedisplayskip
   \let\@listi\@listI}
\DeclareMathSizes{9.5}{9.5}{\@viipt}{\@vpt}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

Hello world $\mathbbm{N}$, $\mathscr{B}$

\end{document}
```

returns the understandable warnings

```
LaTeX Font Warning: Font shape `U/rsfs/m/n' in size <9.5> not available
(Font)              size <9> substituted on input line 22.


LaTeX Font Warning: Font shape `U/bbm/m/n' in size <9.5> not available
(Font)              size <9> substituted on input line 22.


LaTeX Font Warning: Size substitutions with differences
(Font)              up to 0.5pt have occurred.
```

Assuming that I cannot change the font and considering that optically both `\mathbbm{N}` and `$\mathscr{B}` look fine (the difference between 9pt and 9.5pt isn't overwhelming), is there a way to tell `TeX` to use the 9pt size for `\mathbbm` and `\mathscr`? Or is there a way to suppress the warnings for these two math alphabets?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could use the following “second-layer” patch:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{mathrsfs,bbm}

\makeatletter

% taken from the sty file I must use
\renewcommand\normalsize{%
   \@setfontsize\normalsize{9.5}{13}%
   \abovedisplayskip9.5\p@\@plus2\p@\@minus5\p@
   \abovedisplayshortskip\z@\@plus3\p@
   \belowdisplayshortskip6\p@\@plus3\p@\@minus3\p@
   \belowdisplayskip\abovedisplayskip
   \let\@listi\@listI}
\DeclareMathSizes{9.5}{9.5}{\@viipt}{\@vpt}

\makeatother

% further patch:
% Adapted from "ursfs.fd":
\DeclareFontFamily{U}{rsfs}{\skewchar\font127 }
\DeclareFontShape{U}{rsfs}{m}{n}{%
   < -6> rsfs5
   <6-8> rsfs7
   <8- > rsfs10
}{}

% Adapted from "ubbm.fd":
\DeclareFontFamily{U}{bbm}{}
\DeclareFontShape{U}{bbm}{m}{n}
   {  <5> <6> <7> <8> <9> <10> <12> gen * bbm
      <9.5> bbm9 % <<< ADDED
      <10.95> bbm10%
      <14.4>  bbm12%
      <17.28><20.74><24.88> bbm17}{}
\DeclareFontShape{U}{bbm}{m}{sl}
   {  <5> <6> <7> bbmsl8%
      <8> <9> <10> <12> gen * bbmsl
      <9.5> bbmsl9 % <<< ADDED
      <10.95> bbmsl10%
      <14.4> <17.28> <20.74> <24.88> bbmsl12}{}
\DeclareFontShape{U}{bbm}{bx}{n}
   {  <5> <6> <7> <8> <9> <10> <12> gen * bbmbx
      <9.5> bbmbx9 % <<< ADDED
      <10.95> bbmbx10%
      <14.4> <17.28> <20.74> <24.88> bbmbx12}{}
\DeclareFontShape{U}{bbm}{bx}{sl}
   {  <5> <6> <7> <8> <9>
      <9.5> % <<< ADDED
      <10> <10.95> <12> <14.4> <17.28>%
      <20.74> <24.88> bbmbxsl10}{}
\DeclareFontShape{U}{bbm}{b}{n}
   {  <5> <6> <7> <8> <9>
      <9.5> % <<< ADDED
      <10> <10.95> <12> <14.4> <17.28>%
      <20.74> <24.88> bbmb10}{}



\begin{document}

Hello world $\mathbbm{N}$, $\mathscr{B}$

\Huge

Hello world $\mathbbm{N}$, $\mathscr{B}$

\footnotesize

Hello world $\mathbbm{N}$, $\mathscr{B}$

\end{document}
```

Note, however, that I cannot find any mention of the `bbm` fonts in my `pdftex.map` file, and indeed, when I compile your example, pdftex uses PK fonts (`bbm9.600pk`) for characters drawn from that font.  This means that an outline version of those fonts is not available, so the use of the trick shown above entails the creation, run-time, of new PK fonts for the every new size that is actually used.

Comment: Sorry to nag (I never really understood how `LaTeX` handles fonts): I tried and it works also without adding the line `<9.5> bbm9` but just adding `<9.5>` between `<9>` and `<10>` (I hope you understand what I mean). Is it the same?

Comment: @campa: Not quite: if you say `<9.5>bbm9 <10.95>bbm10`, the 9-points font `bbm9` will be used for a size request of 9.5 points, scaling it *up* a tiny bit; on the other hand, if you say `<9.5> <10.95>bbm10`, the 10-points font `bbm10` (the same being used for a request of 10.95 points) will be used for a size request of 9.5 points, scaling it *down* a tiny bit.  You can take your pick: both alternatives are perfectly viable.

Comment: Thanks for the info, but that's not yet quite what I'd like to know: I meant to place it in the first line between `<9>` and `<10>`, the one with `gen * bbm`. What would that do?

Comment: @campa: I did suspect that you could mean that, but actually is does not what you may expect and works, as it were, “by accident”: the NFSS (New Font Selection Scheme) documentation says that fractionary sizes like 9.5 should *not* be used with the `gen` function, since a TFM file name like `bbm9.5.tfm` is not allowed.  It turns out the `bbm9.tfm` it used and scaled `at 9.5` all the same, but I wouldn’t rely on this and I would not recommend your solution.