# Fontsize not affecting some bbm symbols

Tags: math-mode, fontsize

Stemming from [a very similar question I asked previously](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/447302/106804), I was surprised to see **the following symbol from the `bbm` package is not being scaled correctly.**

## The offending symbol

[image]

## MWE

Based on [this solution](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/447304/106804).

```
\documentclass[border=10]{standalone}
\usepackage{lmodern,amsmath,amssymb,bbm,bm,physics,nicefrac,fixcmex}
\begin{document}
    {\fontsize{50}{62.500000}{\rmfamily 
            $\displaystyle\int_\mathbb{R}^{} \sqrt{\dfrac{x}{\sqrt{2\pi\sigma}} 
                \exp(-\dfrac{x^2}{2\sigma^2})}\mathbbm{1}_{\{x > 0\}} \dd{x} = 1 $}}
\end{document}
```

## Possibly relevant

- [Change size of selected math alphabets](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/410966/106804) (the details/solution are a bit beyond me)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `bbm` package uses a font that's only available as bitmap. The related `.fd` file contains

```latex
\DeclareFontShape{U}{bbm}{m}{n}
   {  <5> <6> <7> <8> <9> <10> <12> gen * bbm
      <10.95> bbm10%
      <14.4>  bbm12%
      <17.28><20.74><24.88> bbm17}{}
```

and other similar parts. This means that the font is not available at sizes beyond 25pt (24.88pt, to be precise). Indeed, you get the warnings

```
LaTeX Font Warning: Font shape `U/bbm/m/n' in size <50> not available
(Font)              size <24.88> substituted on input line 6.

LaTeX Font Warning: Font shape `U/bbm/m/n' in size <34.99985> not available
(Font)              size <24.88> substituted on input line 6.

LaTeX Font Warning: Size substitutions with differences
(Font)              up to 25.12pt have occurred.
```

Solutions? Use a different font that's fully scalable, for instance STIX.

```latex
\documentclass[border=10]{standalone}
\usepackage{lmodern,amsmath,amssymb,bm,physics,nicefrac,fixcmex}

\DeclareFontEncoding{LS1}{}{}
\DeclareFontSubstitution{LS1}{stix}{m}{n}

\newcommand{\bbone}{\text{\usefont{LS1}{stixbb}{m}{n}1}}

\begin{document}
{\fontsize{50}{62.5}{\rmfamily 
$\displaystyle\int_\mathbb{R}^{} \sqrt{\dfrac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi\sigma}} 
\exp(-\dfrac{x^2}{2\sigma^2})}\bbone_{\{x>0\}} \dd{x} = 1 $}}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: As pointed out on a [previous comment, when zoomed in the bitmap is ugly](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/447302/fontsize-not-affecting-some-math-symbols#comment1214845_447304). I'll switch to `dsfont`. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You could draw it at the smaller size and scale it.  With the two versions I show, the left uses this approach.  The right uses the OP's original approach.

```
\documentclass[border=10]{standalone}
\usepackage{lmodern,amsmath,amssymb,bbm,bm,physics,nicefrac,fixcmex,scalerel}
\begin{document}
\rmfamily 
            \scaleto{\displaystyle\int_\mathbb{R}^{} \sqrt{\dfrac{x}{\sqrt{2\pi\sigma}} 
                \exp(-\dfrac{x^2}{2\sigma^2})}\mathbbm{1}_{\{x > 0\}} \dd{x} = 1 }{150pt}
    {\fontsize{50}{62.500000}\selectfont{\quad vs.\quad\rmfamily 
            $\displaystyle\int_\mathbb{R}^{} \sqrt{\dfrac{x}{\sqrt{2\pi\sigma}} 
                \exp(-\dfrac{x^2}{2\sigma^2})}\mathbbm{1}_{\{x > 0\}} \dd{x} = 1 $}}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: This is inadvisable for a bitmap font. It would work for an outline font, but those wouldn’t have that problem.

Answer (score 0):

The symbol you want is in Unicode as 𝟙 (U+1D7D9), Mathematical Double-Struck Digit One.  It is available in `unicode-math` as `\Bbbone`, `\symbb{1}` and `\mathbb{1}`, or you can copy or paste in the symbol.  Any recent Unicode math font should contain it (although some older ones do not).  Load your math font with the `Scale=` option and it will automatically scale to the correct height.